# ruby program using instance variables

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance-variables

I am program using instance variables based on Chris Pine's Ruby tutorial: [Link](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=09)

The assignment is:

> Make an OrangeTree class. It should have a  height method which
>   returns its height, and a  oneYearPasses method, which, when called,
>   ages the tree one year. Each year the tree grows taller (however much
>   you think an orange tree should grow in a year), and after some number
>   of years (again, your call) the tree should die. For the first few
>   years, it should not produce fruit, but after a while it should, and I
>   guess that older trees produce more each year than younger trees...
>   whatever you think makes most sense. And, of course, you should be
>   able to countTheOranges (which returns the number of oranges on the
>   tree), and pickAnOrange (which reduces the @orangeCount by one and
>   returns a string telling you how delicious the orange was, or else it
>   just tells you that there are no more oranges to pick this year). Make
>   sure that any oranges you don't pick one year fall off before the next
>   year.

Here is my program:

```
class OrangeTree

    def initialize
        @tree = "orange tree"
        @age = 0
        @height = 0
        @fruit = 0
        @fruitPicked = 0
        puts "your " + @tree + " is budding"
    end

    def age
        puts "your " + @tree + " is #{@age} years old."
        @age = @age
        oneYearPasses
    end

    def height
        puts "your " + @tree + " is growing taller."
        @height = @height
    end

    def fruit
        puts "your " + @tree + " has #{@fruit} oranges."
        @fruit = @fruit
    end

    def pickOrange
        puts "pick how many oranges?"
        @fruitPicked = @fruitPicked + gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "you picked #{@fruitPicked} oranges."
        @fruit = @fruit - @fruitPicked
    end

    def oneYearPasses
        #increase age by 1 each year
        #at the end of each year, all fruits fall off
        if @age >= 0
            @age = @age + 1
            @fruit = @fruit - @fruit    
        end

        #tree keeps growing until it reaches a peak of 20 inches
        if @height >= 0 and @height < 20
            @height = @height + 1
        else
            puts "your " + @tree + " is no longer growing taller."
        end

        #tree starts producing fruit at age 3, each year it will be able to 
        #produce more fruit then subsequent years by multiples of 2
        if @age >= 3
            @fruit = @fruit + (@age * 2)
        end

        #the amount of fruit that is picked
        if @age >= 3
            @fruitPicked = @fruitPicked + @fruitPicked
        end

        if age > 20 and @fruit = 0
            puts "your tree died"
        end
    end
end

orange = OrangeTree.new
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.age
orange.fruit
orange.pickOrange
orange.fruit
orange.age
orange.age
orange.fruit
orange.pickOrange
```

I have 2 questions: 
1) why doesn't the orange tree die when the age > 20 and fruit = 0?
2) Calling my last line orange.pickOrange, I input 2, but my program tells me I picked 20 oranges. Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: not the cause for your problem but you should (1) not mix string concatenation and string interpolation, use the latter: `puts "your #{@tree} has #{@fruit} oranges."`, (2) use snake case instead of camel case for method names, e.g. `pick_orange`, (3) indent with 2 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Q1

Use **==** for comparison instead of **=**

and use @age which is an **instance variable** used within class instead of age

```
 if age > 20 and @fruit = 0 should be

 if @age > 20 and @fruit == 0  within method **oneYearPasses**
```

Perhaps, **after age of 20, fruit count will not be zero**, it will be more than it, so you should change the condition for fruit there

Answer to Q2

After modifying code to

```
  @age > 20 and @fruit == 0
```

I tried this program and, I input 2, and program says, **"you picked 2 oranges."**

Thanks